# Is a company liable if an employee illegally works across the border?

Tags: united-states, international, tax-law

As a US based company, if an employee illegally works from a foreign country in violation of company policy, will the company be held liable for taxes and fines for this action?

If the company is held liable, what is the extent of the damage, and can the company sue the employee to collect damages?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to provide a definitive answer. Violating a company policy is not automatically an illegal act. Without knowing what was allegedly illegal it is hard to know who has criminal, civil or administrative legal exposure. The precise nature of the company policy and agreements between the employee and the company also matter. I can imagine circumstances when any number of exposures of both the company and/or the employee to third-parties like the government or to each other could arise.

Comment: Why would a company allow an employee to work in violation of _its own_ policy?

Comment: @Greendrake it wouldn't, and nothing in the question suggests that it would.  The question is whether the employee's failure to abide by company policy exposes the company to legal liability.

Comment: @phoog It's hard to imagine how the company could be misled by the employee about his true location. I would expect the company to know about it straight away and fire the employee before he does any work from there.

Comment: Violating company policy is not the same as violating the law.

Comment: @Greendrake on the contrary, it's very easy to imagine.  My company doesn't monitor my location.  Do other companies do this?  How would they know?  What if they find out about it after the employee has already done some work?  The question is a valid one, regardless: it doesn't matter why the company failed to prevent the violation of its policies.  This is [Law.SE], not [workplace.SE], and hypotheticals are explicitly on topic.

Comment: @user6726 nobody said that it was.  But whether the illegal act violated company policy is conceivably relevant to company's level of exposure to legal liability for the act.

Comment: @phoog, it is not clear what the OP "said". I did not say that the OP said that it was. "illegally works from a foreign country in violation of company policy" is ambiguous, OP needs to clarify what act is illegal.

Comment: @user6726 perhaps my reading of this question is influenced by having spent quite a lot of time on [Travel.SE] and [Expatriates.SE], where questions come up frequently about visa requirements for performing remote work for a foreign employer. Most countries require explicit work authorization (Canada being a notable exception). As I see it, the most likely interpretation of the first sentence is that the violation of company policy lies in the fact either that the work was done illegally or that it was performed in a foreign country (the illegal nature of the act being incidental).

Comment: USBasedCompany: as you see from the comments, some clarification of this hypothetical would help: what specific act was illegal?  What specific company policy was violated?  Additionally, jurisdiction matters: what was the foreign country? In what US state is the worker employed?

Answer (score 1):

### You are responsible if you break the law

An employer is vicariously liable for the acts and omissions of your employees in the course of their employment. So, if you or your employee are breaking the law then you can be held to account and punished in whatever way the law provides.

At common law, the employer can seek redress from the employee but such lawsuits are rare and even more rarely successful and are outlawed in soMe jurisdictions.

You are not liable for the acts and omissions of independent contractors. However, many so called “independent contracts” are employment contracts under the hood. If the “contractor” is doing things employees normally do, then they are likely to be considered an employee.

Comment: I don't doubt the general principle expressed here, but, assuming that the illegal act is working in some foreign country without authorization, I cannot imagine how or why the foreign country would pursue the employer.  As an analogy, if a company's employee cheats on income taxes with respect to income earned from employment with that company, is the company vicariously liable?  I wouldn't think so.  In other words, there must be some line between acts for which the employer _would_ and _wouldn't_ be liable, and it seems like a good answer to this question ought to discuss that line.

Comment: @phoog the illegally must be “in the course of employment”. Cheating on income tax isn’t even if the obligation to pay it arose from the employment.